# How can I add a Child in my xml file with fwrite

Tags: php, xml, file

I have a problem when I try to insert a new node to my xml file. I need to add:

```
<ul><loc> mylink</ul></loc>
```

before the last node in my xml file.

I tried the code below, but  it doesn't work and it breaks the last node before I insert the new one:

```
$userfile = "sitemap.xml";
$fh = fopen($userfile, 'r+');
$addUser = "<url><loc>https://www.example.com/Privacy-Policy</loc></url></urlset> ";
fseek($fh, -10, SEEK_END);
fwrite($fh, $addUser);
fclose($fh);
```

This is part of my xml file:

```
<urlset >
    <url>
        <loc>example.com</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>example.com</loc>
    </url>
</urlset>
```

my output is:

```
<urlset >
    <url>
<loc>example1.com</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>example2.com</loc>
    </ur<url>  //<-- See here my xml file broke
        <loc>example2.com</loc>
    </url>
</urlset>
```

Comment: *this is part of my link* link? file ?!? Which code??? Please show your code and be a bit more specific what your goal is

Comment: sorry i was fixed :P
you can see the code now

Comment: Yes, but please add the output which you get now and what you would expect to get

Comment: Manipulating xml by means of raw string manipulation is risky. Why don't you use a parser instead: read the file, parse it. insert the element where you like and the serialize and save the file again.

Comment: why Manipulating xml is risky ? you mean it will broke or security risk ?
and what i should look for to insert element ? ? 
because my goal now to insert the element inside this file

Comment: @user44444 If think arkascha means with "risky", that it is very complicated without breaking the xml file and there are other simpler ways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

(Here I just load the xml file with [`simplexml_load_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php), to create a [`SimpleXMLElement()`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.construct.php). After this you can simply add a child to the root node)

```
<?php

    $xml = simplexml_load_file("file.xml");
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml->asXML());

    $urlChild = $xml->addChild("url", "");
    $urlChild->addChild("loc", "example2.com");

    $xml->asXML("file.xml"); 

?>
```

input file:

```
<urlset >
    <url>
        <loc>example.com</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>example.com</loc>
    </url>
</urlset>
```

output file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<urlset>
    <url>
        <loc>example.com</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>example.com</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>example2.com</loc>
    </url>
</urlset>
```